How can I create a Postgres database installer for Ubuntu without internet access?
How can I create a Postgres database installer for Ubuntu without internet access? Or can I install a PostgreSQL database in Ubuntu without the internet?

Does this answer your question? How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?
